# Meta-introduction for implication in Natural Deduction for intuitionistic Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, natural-deduction, intuitionistic-logic

I am going through a paper entitled [A Tutorial on the Curry-Howard Correspondence](http://www.purelytheoretical.com/papers/ATCHC.pdf) by Darryl McAdams.

The author defines a ternary notation as follow to easily manipulate proof trees (page 6 - line 4):

$\bigstar_{0} \vdash \bigstar_{1} : \bigstar_{2}$

which can be read: "assuming any of the hypotheses in $\bigstar_{0}$, the tree $\bigstar_{1}$ is a proof that $\bigstar_{2}$ holds”.

Following this, it introduces meta-rules of inference like this one:

[image: Meta-rule of inference]

I do not understand why the hypothesis that $\implies I$ is discharging, namely "a", is not declared as follow:

$\Gamma, a: A \vdash \implies I_{\mathcal{a}}(\mathcal(B)):(A\implies B)$

Why do we need to declare "$\mathcal{a}$" in the upper part of the meta-proof tree but not in its lower part? What is the "scope" of "$\mathcal{a}$"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbolism is only a way to "trace" the assumptions to be discharged; the assumption is $A$ and $a$ is a sort of "pointer" to the occurrence of the assumption discharged by the rule. It is not another assumptions.

See page 6 :

> $\Gamma$ is any collection of hypothesis that includes a hypothesis of $A$ named $a$ ...

Compare with : Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA20) (2007), page 16, for the *Natural Deduction* $\to$-introduction rule, an page 20 for a way to "trace" assumptions in a derivation.

Comment: Thank you so much Mauro! Just to check my understanding: since we are assuming A in the upper part of the proof tree it now belongs to $\Gamma$ and there is no need to make the declaration explicit because of that and because "$\mathcal{a}$" already exist?

Comment: @Erwan Aaron - not sure to understand : the "initial" set of assumptions is $\Gamma \cup \{ A \}$; the application of the rule "discharge" the $a$ occurrence of $A$ and $\Gamma$ is the set of assumptions left (of course, can be empty).

Comment: So basically the scope of the pointer "$\mathcal{a}$" on the assumption is the whole meta-proof tree until we discharge it?

Comment: @ErwanAaron - yes; the *sequent calculus* is a "calculus" for the *derivability* relation : $\vdash$. The formula : $\Gamma, A \vdash B$ means that we have a (valid) derivation of $B$ from the set  $\Gamma \cup \{ A \}$ of assumptions; the $\to$-I rule allows us to "transform" this valid derivation into a new one : $\Gamma \vdash A \to B$, i.e. a new derivation of $A \to B$ from the set  $\Gamma$ of assumptions, where the occurrence $a$ of the assumption $A$ has been discharged (i.e. the truth-value of the conclusion is nor more "affected" by $A$).

Comment: Thank you your help and for the great reference, Chiswell and Hodges' Mathematical Logic is a real delight!